# NGINX set server IP from file

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have my NGINX configuration file set like this

```
server {
    listen      /root/myIp;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

This will forward my requests to my nodejs app that is listening on port 3000.

My problem is that I need to get the IP from a file `/root/myIp`

The file only contain the IP thus `cat /root/myIp` will directly display the IP.

Is there a way to use a command or the `cat` output inside the nginx conf ?

Comment: Why would you want to listen to specific ip instead of default all ips?

Comment: Can you change the format of your file? If so - just put <listen 1.2.3.4;> to this file and include it in place of listen directive

Comment: @AlexeyTen Because I need to install nginx on multiple machines with different specific IP (stored in this file).

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler I think that I can change it yes. I will try your solution. Thus I should use `listen /path/to/file` ?

Comment: That doesn't mean nginx must listen to specific ip

Comment: @Alexey How whould you make Nginx listen to all ip ? simply `listen *` ? Are they any risks ?

Comment: `listen 80;` usually works well. Actually I've rarely seen nginx listen to specific IP, and in most cases this leads to some troubles. The only good reason for specific IP I could think of is to listen to localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: @Alexey That seems logical. I will try this solution too

Comment: In production admins usually object to bind to all IPs.

Comment: @Weedose - name you file listen.conf and place in the same folder as nginx.conf. listen.conf should contain <listen 1.2.3.4;> (not including angle bracket  and of course replace with IP you need) Replace listen directive within nginx.conf with include listen.conf; Using this approach you may very simple create listen.conf file by bash script, for example.

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler Thank you ! So what is the best option ? listen to all IPS or the listen.conf ?

Comment: @Weedose - it is your decision. If your server has only one network interface with one IP address assigned - listen to all IPs has no risks, in all others cases I would prefer to specify IP explicitly.

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler I finally use the solution to listen to all IP. Thanks again

Comment: @AlexeyTen I finally use the solution to listen to all IP. Thanks again